# Multiplication table not working Array index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I added the  plus 1 here:  for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < y + 1; j++) 
so that the program would grab all the numbers except the one right before what I mean is..
If I enter 10 for the Maximum x value and 10 for the y (without the plus 1) this is what the output shows:

Would you like a power table or a multiplication table?
 Press 1 for Power
 Press 2 for Multiplication
2
Maximum x value?
10
Maximum y value?
10

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
2  4  6  8  10  12  14  16  18  
3  6  9  12  15  18  21  24  27  
4  8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  
5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  
6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  
7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  
8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  
9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

I don't know why this wont work please help this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int defaulVa = 1;
    int defaulEx = 2;

    System.out.println("Would you like a power table or a multiplication table?"
            + "\n Press 1 for Power"
            + "\n Press 2 for Multiplicatiion");
    int a = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Maximum x value?");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Maximum y value?");
    int y = sc.nextInt();

    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("How would you like your base?"
                    + "\nPress 1 for preset value"
                    + "\nPress 2 for acending value");
            int answer = sc.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("What value?");
                    int value = sc.nextInt();
                    powerTable(x, y, value, defaulVa);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("How would you like your exponent?"
                            + "\nPress 1 for preset value"
                            + "\nPress 2 for acending value");
                    int d = sc.nextInt();

                    switch (d) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("What value?");
                            int d2 = sc.nextInt();
                            powerTable(x, y, defaulVa, d2);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            powerTable(x, y, defaulVa, defaulEx);
                            break;

                        default:

                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            multiplicationTable(x, y);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("I see you can't follow simple instructions...");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }

}

public static int[][] powerTable(int arrayDimensionX, int arrayDimensionY, int value, int value2) {
    int[][] myArray;
    myArray = new int[arrayDimensionX][arrayDimensionY];
    for (int i  = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (value == 1) {
                value = myArray[i][j] = i * j;
            } else if (value != 1) {
                value++;
            }
            myArray[i][j] = ((int) Math.pow(value, value2));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < arrayDimensionX; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arrayDimensionY; j++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return myArray;
}

public static int[][] multiplicationTable(int x, int y) {
    int[][] myArray;
    myArray = new int[x][y];
    for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are `0` indexed (they start at `0` and the last index is `length - 1`)

I would say...

```
for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Should be...

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You'd need to change the loop that builds the table to look something more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = (1 + i) * (1 + j); // <-- Modify the indices here instead...
    }
}
```

Have a look at [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much. You don't know how much you have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your `multiplicationTable` function have an `int[][]` return type, when you return null? Would be better to just make it a void function, if you don't plan on having it return the array.

Anyway, since all the function does in print to the screen, the function is over complicated. Could be made much simpler, something like this:

```
public static void multiplicationTable(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)
            System.out.print(i * j);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But if you want it left as is, your `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is likely occuring here:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Because x and y are the size of the array, making your loop go to `i < x + 1` and `i < y + 1` will throw the exception, because it is trying to access a non-existing index. If you change it to `i < x` and `i < y` it shouldn't throw the exception:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < y; j++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

However, even that will not give you the desired output, as it skips the first element of the array, because array indexes start at 0, not 1, meaning the multiplications for 1 will be missing from your table.